# Getting id from a parameter in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a date picker function that is supposed to turn an input field into a datepicker.
it runs something like this;

```
function activateDatePicker(id){
    $(function() {
            $(id).datepicker({
                defaultDate: "+1w",
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                numberOfMonths: 3,
            });
    });
}
```

Another function would create the input tag necessary and call the activateDatePicker function in order to turn it into a jquery datepicker, for example

```
function createInputTag(input){
    document.getElementById("sometag").innerHTML = 
                                  "<input id="+input+" />";
    activateDatePicker(input);
}
```

That input could be anything, and I would use createInputTag to create multiple datepickers, each with a different ID. at the moment it does nothing though, and the console does not show any erros. does anyone know why? and what I can do to fix it? I would prefer to have a solution in javascript, but jquery is also good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in addition to @bipen's response, you should probably not use the $(function(){...}); inside your function:

```
function activateDatePicker(id)
{
        $(id).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            numberOfMonths: 3,
        });   
}
```

Comment: I've just discovered the solution and it's unrelated to the datepicker. Thanks for your time anyways, your answer came the closest to solving it.

Answer (score 1):

your selector is incorrect

```
 $(id).datepicker({
```

should be

```
  $('#'+id).datepicker({
```

input too..

```
 "<input id="+input+" />";
```

In HTML, the `<input>` tag has no end tag.

i don't think u need to use ready function inside a function ...

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that, no errors from the console either

Comment: just want to make sure u have an element with an id `sometag` in ur html ..:)....